# Execute bumpbox from flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, mootools

I have searched alot on google with no luck.

I want a flv film to play in a bumpbox window when a button is pushed in a flash banner. Does anybody know how?

I tried looking for some support on artvipers own site but no luck either.

[Artviper - bumpbox](http://www.artviper.net/website-tools/bumpbox-lightbox.php)

(This is my first post, so please be gentle :))

Answer (score 1):

No idea about bumpbox but this simple tip should put you on the right track.

You will need two things to achieve your goal:
- embed your banner with [allowScriptAccess](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html) set to true
- create a proxy object in the js side that will interact between your banner and the bumpbox script like this:

```
var proxy_object = {
    do_something: function(params) {
        // some code here to open bumpbox and display your other movie
    }
};
```

Then from your banner you just call `ExternalInterface.call('proxy_object.do_something', some_params_here, if_needed)` as needed.

you can always get some more help on how ExternalInterface works at the [Adobe Flash help](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)